# Manipular todas imagens de um diretório sem precisar acessar

Tags: javascript, imagem, loop, diretório

O Script abaixo, se encarrega de mostrar uma sequência de imagens em uma determinada taxa de quantidade (num), desta forma se faz necessário definir um número de imagens. Confira:

## Código

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>

     var dir = 'imagens' // Pasta Minhas imagens

      var num = '5' // Limite a mostrar

      window.onload = function(){

      for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

      document.body.innerHTML += "<img src='"+dir+"/"+i+".jpg'>";

        }
    }

    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Esta rotina(bloco de código) possui dois parâmetros, o primeiro é o **dir**(diretório) definido na marcação que será responsável por armazenar as imagens.

Já o segundo parâmetro é referente as opções de exibição, esse parâmetro é um **num**(número) que possui a quantidade máxima a mostrar na página

***Não quero ficar setando um número limite, desejo que o próprio script se encarrega de trazer até a última imagem da pasta***

> **NOTA** - *Todas imagens dentro do respectivo diretório/pasta deverá seguir o mesmo conceito, sendo todas deverão ser nomeados por número ordinais, `Exemplo: 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg 5.jpg etc...` Somente assim conseguirá mostra-las com sucesso.*

Comment: Javascript só no front não é capaz de acessar diretamente o disco. Está usando node.js, php? Porquê o código que postou não faz o que diz que faz.

Comment: A contagem de arquivos (para saber o total) tem que ser com uma linguagem server-side. PHP, por exemplo.
Mas se for usar php pra contar, pode usar pra exibir também.
Não vejo outra solução.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique o que importa da resposta linkada nao é o `limite` mas sim a "impossibilidade" de fazer o que queres com *garantia de sucesso*. Embora a resposta que eu dei *possa* funcionar - não é, de todo, a melhor maneira de resolver o problema presente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de pensar... (teoricamente) Há uma maneira de fazeres isto client-side. Não é, **de todo**, aconselhável.

```
window.loadPatternImages = function() {

  var _this = this;
  this.fileTemplate = "%.jpg";
  this.fileDirectory = "/images/";
  this.imageIndex = 0;

  this.loadImage = function loadImage(src, index) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = src.replace('%', index);
    image.onload = function() {
      _this.imageIndex++;
      _this.loadImage(_this.fileDirectory + _this.fileTemplate, _this.imageIndex);
      //document.querySelector('.loaded-images').appendChild(image);
    };
    image.onerror = function(e) {
        var textNode = document.createTextNode('Loaded ' + _this.imageIndex + ' images from ' + src);
      //document.querySelector('.loaded-images').appendChild(textNode);
      _this.errorOccurred(e)
    };
  };

  this.errorOccurred = function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  };

  this.loadImage(_this.fileDirectory + _this.fileTemplate, _this.imageIndex);

};
```

O que tens que fazer é criar uma uma `self-recurring-function` que se chama a si mesmo com o intuito de fazer uma nova imagem no DOM e por-lhe um `src`. Quando essa imagem fizer load, então faz load à proxima. Se essa imagem nao existir, ela retorna um erro pondo então um fim à recursividade.

Podes depois usar `image` para fazer append no DOM. [FiddleJs](https://jsfiddle.net/7foxtpLL/1/)

No entanto, é bem mais facil meteres um servidor a dizer-te quais as imagens que tens que fazer load.

Answer (score 0):

**MoshMage** disse - *"Há uma maneira de fazeres isto client-side. O que tens que fazer é criar uma "self-recurring-function" que se chama a si mesmo"*

Numa tradução livre *self-recurring-function*, quer dizer - *função recursiva*

Pois bem, em JavaScript existem duas funções temporizadoras embutidas (built-in timer functions), `setTimeout` e `setInterval`
que podem ser usadas para chamar funções de retorno (callback functions) após um determinado tempo. Veja um exemplo de uso disso:

```
setTimeout(function recursiva() { 

document.body.innerHTML += "."; 

setTimeout(recursiva, 1000); 

}, 1000);
```

**jsbin** - [Demonstração em funcionamento](http://jsbin.com/rumobeyuvu/edit?js,output)

Como você pode ver este código acima, chama a função `recursiva` que, quando processada, faz uma chamada para `setTimeout(recursiva,1000);` que chama `recursiva` de novo após 1 segundo, tendo assim quase o mesmo efeito de `setInterval` enquanto permanece mais resistente à erros não intencionais que podem ocorrer.

**MoshMage** ressaltou - *"Podes depois usar image para fazer append no DOM"*

Então eu decidi fazê-lo assim:

```
var numero = 0;

numero++;

var figura = document.createElement('img');

figura.src = "/images/'+numero+'.jpg";

document.body.appendChild(figura);
```

Agora em uma estrutura pré-montada em `auto-recorrente-função` ficaria deste modo:

```
var numero = 0;

numero++;


setTimeout(function recursiva() { 


    var figura = document.createElement('img');

    figura.src = "/images/'+numero+'.jpg";

    document.body.appendChild(figura);


setTimeout(recursiva, 1000); 

}, 1000);
```

Mas, de acordo com `setInterval()` é a melhor maneira nesse caso. Enquanto a `setInterval()` chama a função “infinitamente” sempre no mesmo intervalo de tempo.
E para pausar a função usa-se `clearInterval()`. Passando como parâmetro o nome do seu intervalo.

```
var intervalo = window.setInterval(function() {

document.body.innerHTML += "."; 

}, 50);

window.setTimeout(function() {

    clearInterval(intervalo);

}, 3000);
```

**jsbin** - [Exemplo do evento clearInterval em funcionamento](https://jsbin.com/viqapijoda/edit?js,console,output)

**MoshMage** finalizou dizendo - *"Se essa imagem não existir, ela retorna um erro pondo então um fim à recursividade."*

Ótimo, ele quis demonstrar algo pelo método `OnError`, tipo assim:

```
figura = document.createElement('img'); 

figura.onload = function() { 

document.body.appendChild(figura);
}
figura.onerror = function() {  

//display error

alert('Erro Fatal!')
}
figura.src = 'http://www.monkie.com.br/logo.png'; 

// Para prever tal comportamento na prática onError, 
// altere a url de destino retirando "logo.png"
// deixando-o http://www.monkie.com.br/ e teste novamente.
```

**jsbin** - [Exemplo do evento OnError em funcionamento](https://jsbin.com/senuvudequ/edit?js,output)

Contudo isso podemos ver em execução o resultado final, confira:

```js
const figura = document.createElement('img');

var diretorio = 'http://mplayer.xpg.uol.com.br/img/'

var numero = 0;

var intervalo = window.setInterval(visualizar, 1000)
function visualizar() {
figura.src = diretorio+numero+'.jpg'
document.getElementById("foto").appendChild(figura);
    numero++;
}

figura.onerror = function() 
{  
clearInterval(intervalo);
alert('Há '+numero+' fotos em '+diretorio);
}
```

```html
<span id="foto">&nbsp;</span>
```

## Explicação snippet

Detalhe, se souber que o valor da variável `figura` não vai mudar, utiliza-se a declaração reservada [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Não é possível chamar uma função anônima se ela não for atribuída a uma variável. No caso a função anônima esta atribuída a variável `figura` precedida de ponto "." seguida do método `onerror`, tornando-se acessível apenas quando esta variável é acessível, se a imagem não existir, o browser interpretar um erro de carregamento(load) de uma imagem, disparado pelo método OnError. Esta função anônima usa-se `clearInterval()` que por sua vez é exatamente a de permitir passá-la como parâmetro o nome do seu intervalo, matando assim o processo contínuo(recursivo) da função `visualizar()`. Logo é disparado o *evento* `alert()` que exibi o total de Imagens carregada com sucesso, ou seja, a quantidade exata do que ha no diretório.

***LEMBRETE - "Todas imagens devem estar nomeados em numerais ordinais, caso contrário impossível."***

> Enfim, coube-me esclarecer na prática a teoria dada para cada parágrafo dito por MoshMage.